# Is it possible to have an Illuminated Standard temperature and pressure pocket inside of a comet?

Tags: science-based, space, atmosphere, asteroids

The title is fairly self explanatory. A pocket inside a comet, able to have liquid water and similar pressures to earth. I want a realistic and science based way to achieve this.

requirements:

- Must have liquid water
- Must have light for photosynthesis
- Must reoccur every orbit, if possible it can stay even at the aphelion, but that isn’t required.
- It must be internal, not on the surface.

Things up to you

- Any type of star is fine
- Orbital parameters can be whatever, but they must still be reasonably a comet.
- The chemical makeup can be anything, but it must contain at minimum all basic parts of life.
- It can be caused by any method, as long as it happens repeatedly, and is non artificial. It does not have to be likely in any individual comet though.

When answering this question you should evaluate the possibility of the described conditions being met. Any parameters not specified can be assumed to be changed.

Comment: Natural or artificial? Natural is difficult, because the required heat source will eventually melt the comet. Also, there aren't any natural heat/light sources that fit the bill. Artificial is practical with a fusion reactor, but you'll also need refrigeration to keep from melting the comet.

Comment: Please edit that into the question, since it's an important limitation on answers.

Comment: Let's assume this is plausible. In Real Life the comet's Earth-like atmosphere would last from the moment it entered the goldilocks zone to the moment it left it, then again (probably over a different spot on the comet) on the outbound journey. If you're looking for realistic, your problem isn't the pocket, it's any life you expect to be in it. At perihelion all life is dead from heat and high-energy particles (no magnetosphere) and at aphelion (and a lot earlier) everything's dead from the cold.

Comment: BTW, what does "STP" mean? When I search for "STP Pocket" on Google I get a plush space rocket on Etsy and a bunch of STP Racing pocket protectors and T-shirts. In general, whenever you're tempted to use the phrase, "... self explanatory," that should be a flag that you're skipping necessary details.

Comment: @JBH “At perihelion all life is dead from heat and high-energy particles … everything's dead from the cold” while these are reasonable objections, bacterial spores (endospores) can survive all of that, fairly easily. While it is a bit of an assumption that endospores would evolve, that is not the focus of the question.

Comment: @JBH STP means Standard temperature and pressure. That seemed like on obvious term, but even if it wasn’t, the question explains what it means.

Comment: @Topcode Please provide citations to prove that bacteria can survive comet perihelion and aphelion.

Comment: @JBH I would disagree on the radiation. Water is a very good shield material when in bulk. However it is a very good shield ensuring no energy gets to the core.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor Please provide citations to prove what thickness of water would be necessary to protect bacteria at its center at perihelion and aphelion.

Comment: @JBH yes it does. I specific that the pocket is “STP” this is clearly an attribute of the pocket, I later explain that it can support earth like pressures with liquid water. Personally I would expect for you to search terms when you don’t understand them.

Comment: @JBH that’s a great opinion to have. Unfortunately, I do not care and it is not my responsibility to teach everyone what every single term means. If you think it’s such an exotic term, great, someone could think that water is an exotic term.

Comment: @JBH course. [temperature of comet at perihelion](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-surface-temperature-over-one-rotation-at-perihelion-for-two-cases-Sublimation-is_fig3_41626037) and I’ll let you read the Wikipedia page on what Endospores can survive.

Comment: You're being very obstinate. I told you what a google search produced and yet you still think it's an obvious term. Put those big boy pants on and [edit] your post to clarify a non-standard term.

Comment: @JBH “told you what a google search produced” yes, and unfortunately I do not care what your search produces, because my searches easily produce standard temperature and pressure. I have no idea why you think it is non-standard, it’s literally called standard.

Comment: Yes, STP *is* a common abbreviation for [standard temperature and pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature_and_pressure), if one is a chemist. It is also a common abbreviation for [shielded twisted pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shielded_twisted_pair) or [Spanning Tree Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol), if one is a network engineer. It is also a semi-well-known brand of motor oil, an abbreviation for sodium triphosphate, and many others. This is a common problem with [TLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym)...

Comment: I read the article you provided. I [also read about the comet](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/asteroids-comets-and-meteors/comets/9p-tempel-1/in-depth/). "Comet 9P/Tempel 1 ***orbits the sun within the asteroid belt***, which lies between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter. Tempel 1 last reached perihelion (closest approach to the sun) in 2016." I must admit that your conditions allow for the orbit to be anywhere, but a surface temp of +52℃ at perihelion means little here. Fig. 1 shows the surface temp at "midnight" to be -123℃. Assuming non-existent homogeneity, your core is -35℃. Try again?

Comment: Thank you for fixing the abbreviation problem. Next issue. What do you mean by "illuminated?" Your conditions are in conflict. One requires the pocket to be internal to the comet. Another says their must be light for photosynthesis. Ice isn't that transparent, would boil away at perihelion if it were thin enough, and I can't find quick proof that a comet can be made of quartz.

Comment: And that Wiki about endospores tells us, "While significantly resistant to heat and radiation, endospores can be destroyed by burning or by autoclaving at a temperature exceeding the boiling point of water, 100 °C. ... Prolonged exposure to ionising radiation, such as x-rays and gamma rays, will also kill most endospores."

Comment: Having said all that: This question has its own merit, once you've resolved the conflict between conditions, and I'll change my downvote to an upvote once you've fixed it and delete all my comments. But I've yet to see sufficient evidence that exceeds the [tag:science-fiction] tag to address my first comment. But it will go, too, once you've cleared up the conflict.

Comment: @JBH For water shielding [this space stack answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/1826) is relevant. 7cm to cut ionizing radiation in half.  Water is used in nuclear plants for spent fuel cooling. Not as good against gamma as lead, but once dealing with meters thick of water, it will shield.

Comment: @JBH you are not welcome (:

Comment: @JBH the rest of your issues actually just seem like you want me, to answer the question myself in the question. Which I am not actually going to do because that’s not how questions work. Unfortunately it seems as though this question already has fatal downvote syndrome, and so I will be effective immediately abandoning it.

Comment: If that's your choice you are, yet again, making a bad choice. Most of this question's problems were brought about by your obstinance. Had you simply addressed everything quickly not a single downvote would have occurred. I've offered a path to clean everything up after a final fix that is, obviously, fatal (even ZeissIkon pointed it out). Reversing my vote raises the question to -1. But that's up to you.

Comment: @JBH Once you are more experienced with the worldbuilding stack exchange you may hear about a frame challenge. This is a type of answer that is where you can express the complains about how “Ice isn't that transparent, would boil away”

Comment: Obstinance... Once you are more experienced with the worldbuilding stack exchange you may realize that you are expected to be consistent with your conditions, limitations, restrictions, requirements, and tags. You tagged your question [tag:science-based], You can't claim it's a frame challenge when you've asked a question that fails the tags you used. My offer to clean all this up will remain open.

Comment: @JBH "consistent with your conditions, limitations, restrictions, requirements, and tags" they are. your opinion that they aren't is just that, an opinion. Why you have this opinion is nobody's knowledge but your own, and nobody's problem but your own.

Comment: Oh good grief. You deserve what happened here.

Comment: @JBH "what happpened here" idk what you think has happened other than you getting mad at your inability to google terms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140450/discussion-between-topcode-and-jbh).

Answer (score 1):

There is reason to believe that large enough comets may contain liquid under their ice shell -- in that a large enough comet becomes a Kuiper belt object like Pluto, Eris, or Haumea, any of which could have acquired a molten layer and, via various mechanisms, retained such a region for a geologically long time (a billion years or so?).

Initial heating can come from accretion energy -- that is, the small "snowflakes" and dust particles impacting on the comet as it forms over a period of eons will each contribute energy that can only be lost by radiation from the surface of the composite body.  Later, radioactivity of the denser material at the core will contribute and can lead to the heat persisting for millions of years (there is a current hypothesis that Ceres may *still* have a molten salt water layer like Europa's subsurface ocean, and it's been proposed that Pluto might as well -- the insulating power of kilometers of *anything* shouldn't be underestimated).

If such a sub-ocean does form, however, there won't be any light inside and nowhere will the pressure be as low as "Standard Temperature and Pressure" -- not with kilometers of ice on top, even under less than 1% gravity.  Therefore such a pocket would have to be artificial, and as such can be anything your worldbuilding heart desires.